# Linux boot error, ACPI Error: no handler for Region?

Tags: linux, boot, boot-loader

Recently, my Linux mint cannot boot up. And with the error message

[image: error message]

I have searched a lot. And tried to edit /etc/fstab file to mount root partition but it didn't work.

I suspect that my SSD hard drive is broken. And I get this error sometimes.

My environment：

I have install Linux mint under /dev/sdb1, and install Windows under /dev/sdc1.

Is there any problem with my hardware?

[image: no device]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ACPI errors are most likely not relevant here. They seem to refer to an inconsistency in your system's ACPI tables referring to the ACPI embedded controller, and possibly to GPU. All those messages are output within the first second of kernel start-up: the timestamp at the beginning of the lines is `[   0.957786]` or less.

The lines with the timestamp `[   37.871909]` or later indicate that a (S)ATA `READ FPDMA QUEUED` command has failed on `ata6.00`. In other words, your disk reported that it cannot perform a read command that was sent to it. Yes, that is a pretty strong indicator that your disk may be failing.

The `error: no such device: EEBACEF9BACEBCF9` might be caused by a UUID reference in `/etc/fstab` referring to a failing disk. `EEBACEF9BACEBCF9` looks like a filesystem "UUID" the `blkid` command might display for a NTFS filesystem. So I think your `/dev/sdc` disk might be dying or already dead, since you said that's your Windows disk.

Comment: It is true that my sdc SSD disk is dead. Thank you for your explain.